# Download PDF according to variable passed?

Tags: pdf

I noticed a URL passing a variable to a PDF file.

.../1098e.pdf?year=2014

Can someone explain how this works? Where would the logic to handle the request be placed?

(I'm not sure what language the site was built in).

Answer (score 1):

With this info, it's impossible to know how the server side works or even what language is implementing the response.
The only thing you can assume is that the response PDF file is being generated dynamically according to the parameter provided (if you can see that if you change the parameter the output changes somehow). But even this could be mistaken, since it could be that you are requesting a file directly, and hence the parameter would be ignored.

Answer (score 0):

Request handles some web application (apache & php for example).

On the web server, you can configure which urls are files and which urls handles by the application. It does not matter if the application processes `/info.png`, `/info` or `/info.php`